# Cant get react native project to run on android

Tags: android, linux, react-native, manjaro

I've been at this for a whole day.

I created a new project using `npx react-native init Project`. But If I try to run it on android I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Incompatible magic value 0 in class file java/util/logging/ErrorManager
```

I've went through the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) many times. When I run `npx react-native doctor`, I get this:

```
Android
✓ JDK
✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
  - Versions found: N/A
  - Version supported: 29.0.3
✓ ANDROID_HOME
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there were a few things that were causing this issue.

> ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android

It seems that `npx react-native doctor` looks for **/opt/android-studio**, after placing my android studio in /opt/, it was able to detect it.

> ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on
> Android
>
> - Versions found: N/A
> - Version supported: 29.0.3

From what I understood, react native uses **sdkmanager** script to look for sdk which comes with **command line tools** when you install android studio. In my case, when I ran the script it was giving me errors. The reason for that was that I hadn't created **JAVA_HOME** environment variable. So, after creating the environment variable and adding it to PATH, the sdkmanager script ran successfully and so did the react native project.

**TL;DR**

1. You need to have your android studio folder in opt and it must be named **android-studio**.
2. Install android sdk command line tools(latest) and add it to your PATH like this `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`
3. Also create `JAVA_HOME` and add it to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I want to extend @Tayyab answer a bit. I'm facing a similar problem where `npx react-native doctor` can't find either `android studio` and `android SDK`.

There are a few things that I try but one thing that I did different from @Tayyab is

`Install android sdk command line tools(latest) and add it to your PATH like this export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`

So here is my problem, I installed the latest CLI from Android studio but it doesn't work. What I did was install the older version instead (version 10) and everything works just fine.

With the `android studio` directory, as @Tayyab said it need to be in `/opt` folder. So it doesn't matter how you install android studio you need to move it there because that is where react-native doctor is looking for your android studio. However, if you are not moving there your application might be able to run just fine but the react-native doctor just can't find it.

Answer (score -1):

It's look you don't have installed Android Studio in your system.
Try to install from official site https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

Or use snap https://snapcraft.io/install/android-studio/manjaro

`sudo snap install android-studio --classic`

Comment: I've it installed. How do i tell react native it's location?

Comment: What you get now using `npx react-native doctor` ? After install Android Studio you need: 
"3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable" https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: The output of that command is in main post. Anyways, I've solve the problem.